# SwiftUI button image inset

Tags: swiftui

Is there same thing as ImageEdgeInsets for SwiftUI. For example I have button 60x60. And want to make inset for image inside.

```
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0.0){
            Section{
                Button(action: {
                    if self.accountViewModel.signInContext == .quote{
                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }else{
                        self.viewController?.dismiss(animated: true)
                    }
                }){
                    Image("Close Icon").renderingMode(.template).padding(.vertical, 20).padding(.horizontal, 20).foregroundColor(.white).scaledToFit()
                }
                .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                Rectangle().line().padding(.horizontal, -30)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `.padding` is for that purpose, just needed to make image resizable. I suppose you need the following

```
Image("Close Icon")
    .renderingMode(.template)
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    .padding(.vertical, 20).padding(.horizontal, 20)
```